# JS fetch returning 0 array length from flask

Tags: javascript, python, json, post, fetch

I have a very simple and straightforward code:

Py:

```
@blueprint.route('/Ajax', methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
def Ajax():                
    Graph1 = [10,10,10,10,10]
    return jsonify(Graph1)
```

JS

```
fetch('/Ajax')
.then(function (response) {
  theData = Object.values(response); 
  console.log(theData);
  return theData; 
})
```

Yet I am getting:

[image]

I am not sure why this is the reason.

Comment: `response` does not contain the response data ... try `fetch('/Ajax')
.then(response => response.json()).then(data => here is the data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure about your Python code but with [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) in js you need to convert the response to `json` first.

This should work:

```js
fetch('/Ajax')
  .then(response => response.json())  // <--- this has been added
  .then(function (response) {
    theData = Object.values(response); 
    console.log(theData);
    return theData; 
  });
```

Comment: I have 5 minutes left haha. Definitely will :)